# Keras model softmax output not summing to 1

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have an LSTM text generator where the final layer is a Dense layer with a softmax activation to decide which character to output. 
To get the character from this output I use a random selection where the probabilities for each character are set by this output.
However, the line doing the randomisation causes a crash because the output of the softmax function does not sum to 1. 
I checked the sums manually with the sum() function on a single output from the generator, and the sum is always extremely close to 1. like, '0.9999998640269041' or '1.000000050291419'

Here is the generator model

```
activ='elu'
optim=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, clipnorm=0.1)
G = Sequential()
G.add(LSTM(700,activation=activ,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),input_shape=(None, GnoiseSize),return_sequences=True,kernel_initializer='random_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros'))
G.add(Dropout(0.5))
G.add(BatchNormalization())
G.add(LSTM(500,activation=activ,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),return_sequences=True,kernel_initializer='random_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros'))
G.add(Dropout(0.5))
G.add(BatchNormalization())
G.add(LSTM(200,activation=activ,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),return_sequences=True,kernel_initializer='random_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros'))
G.add(Dropout(0.5))
G.add(BatchNormalization())
G.add(Dense(n_vocab,activation='softmax'))

#G.load_weights("G.h5")

G.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optim, metrics=['accuracy'], sample_weight_mode='temporal')
```

and here is a test of its output that doesnt sum to 1:

```
allText[0:numGeneratedText,:,:] = G.predict(Gnoise)
print(sum(self.allEpisodes_states[0,0,:]))
charIndex = np.random.choice(range(0, n_vocab), p=self.allEpisodes_states[0,0,:])
```

I'm guessing its some sort of rounding error but I've set allText to float64 dtype and it doesnt help. I don't know where the rounding or whatever imprecision error is taking place. Is it in Keras itself? (I'm using Tensorflow as a backend).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I tried saving the output of G.predict into a new variable and that fixed it apparently.
i.e. instead of:

```
allText = np.zeros((max_Episodes, max_steps, n_vocab)
allText[0:max_Episodes,:,:] = G.output
charIndex = np.random.choice(range(0, n_vocab), p=allText[0,0,:])
```

I did:

```
newVariable = G.output
charIndex = np.random.choice(range(0, n_vocab), p=newVariable[0,0,:])
```

and it gave me charIndex without any problems.